# Choosing which bean to reference in spring?

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I have a spring project which contains a bean definition file containing a bean which references another bean as a property, for example

```
<bean id="aBean" class="org.test.class">
    <property class="org.test.A" autowire="byType"/>
</bean>
```

This bean definition file will be imported by other spring projects which may or may not contain beans which extend org.test.A.

What I'd like to do is that if an extension implementation of org.test.A exists (i.e org.test.B) I'd like to reference that in the property, otherwise just reference org.test.A.

I have been doing some research on the matter but have not arrived at an answer. I tried writing a custom TypeFilter but that just seems to allow me to return true or false whether a class should be returned or not, rather than checking all existing bean definitions for a class and choosing one.

Is such a thing possible? If so, how would one go about doing that?

The idea is to avoid to have to rewrite a bunch of bean definitions which reference each other (and will for the most part all be the same in every project anyway) and only write the implementation of a referenced bean.

Any input on the matter is appreciated.

----- UPDATE 1 ------

I have given it a try using @Primary and so far no luck. No errors but the class being used is not the one with @Primary.

The main class org.test.A extends another class (org.test.Whatever), then in my servlet context I have the following

```
<bean id="someID" class="org.someclass">
    <property name="realm" ref="testBean" />
</bean>
```

And then I created another org.test.B class which extends org.test.A and has both @Component and @Primary but no go. Spring seems to be loading the class but not using it.

----- UPDATE 2 -----

OK I think I know what is happening. The class which I am autowiring (Which I have no control over the source code) happens to have 2 set methods, 1 which takes a single class and one that takes a collection of that class. Spring seems to think that because it finds several beans of the same class, it should autowire the set which takes a collection instead of autowiring the set which takes a single instance.

How do I specify, in the context xml which I am instancing the class, which method should be autowired? I don't understand why spring won't allow me to use autowire attribute on a property. I can only set autowire on the bean which leaves spring to choose which method to autowire. :S

Comment: could you post your class-code with the annotations

Comment: Please read my updates above. It seems the issue is elsewhere. I created some unit test to speed up the process and it seems spring is doing some auto magic stuff which is really annoying and I cannot find a way to get control over which method is autowires

Comment: i dont get what oyu mean by this: How do I specify, in the context xml which I am instancing the class, which method should be autowired?

Comment: The class I am autowiring happens to have 2 setter methods, 1 which takes an instance of class A and another which takes a Collection of class A. Because of that it looks like spring will magically choose to autowire the setter which takes a collection if it happens to find more than 1 bean of that class, giving me no choice to choose which setter method to autowire. I have now managed to get things working with byType autowire though and primary and you suggested

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`@Primary`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html) annotation may help you.

If you have more than 1 implentation, the one annotated with `@Primary` is used

Comment: That sounds like it could be the answer however will it work if the class is a subclass of the wanted class?

In the example above, if I set @Primary on org.test.B which happens to extend org.test.A, will it work since org.test.A is just a subclass of it?

Comment: as far as i know: yes. if you use the autowire annotation, an instance of B would be created and used

Comment: ps: i attached a Link: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html

Comment: Hi, upvoting and acception comes once I have managed to actually verify it works. :)

Please see update on main post

Comment: I made some further tests and I am guessing @Primary only works with main class. I autowired the bean byType and used the class name which the foirst file extends (org.test.Whatever) but I got errors saying it could not find a bean with that class even though it clearly exists.

Comment: The solution at the end was to first create a bean which contains the property to be autowired, and an implementation of the property as well on a bean

<bean id="someID" class="org.someclass" autowire="byType">
</bean>

<bean class="org.test.A" primary="false" />

Then in another project I created a class org.test.B which extends org.test.A and annotated it \@Primary and \@Component and that seemed to do the job

Answer (score 0):

You should use [spring factory method for instantiating this bean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.8/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-class-instance-factory-method). Alternatively, use lookup-method injection like in [this](http://thecafetechno.com/tutorials/spring/lookup-getter-method-injection-example/) example.

Comment: I am not sure how the factory method would work in this case, could you elaborate? As for the lookup method, it sounds like the class would have to already load a method which get overriden by the lookup method, while in my case the class just has a setter method.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do this using SpEL
I have two implementations of DataStrategy type with bean ids testDataStrategy and realDataStrategy

I can choose between the beans by setting the property 'data.strategy' in the Property file in my Java project.

```
<bean id="myBeanId" class="com.some.path.MyBeanClass" >
    <property name="dataStrategy" value="#   {'${data.strategy}'.equalsIgnoreCase('TEST_DATA') ? testDataStrategy : realDataStrategy}" />
</bean>
```